# GridView RowDataBound, Deleted cells reappear

Tags: c#

I am working on a .Net Project and I have some problems with GridView.

I have several buttons in my page. When I click the button which binds my GridView everything is OK, but after that, when I click on some other button there appears one more cell, which is empty, at the end of Rows which contains the text "Monday".

Can someone tell me what the problem is?

Thanks

This is my code.

```
       protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
       {
           if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Contains("Monday"))
           {   
                e.Row.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                e.Row.ForeColor = Color.White;
                e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 2;
                e.Row.Cells.Remove(e.Row.Cells[1]);
                e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                e.Row.Cells[2].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                e.Row.Cells[3].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                e.Row.Cells[4].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
           }
           else
           {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Width = 45;
                e.Row.Cells[1].Width = 400;
                e.Row.Cells[2].Width = 40;
                e.Row.Cells[3].Width = 40;
                e.Row.Cells[4].Width = 40;
                e.Row.Cells[5].Width = 40;
                e.Row.Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                e.Row.Cells[2].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                e.Row.Cells[3].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                e.Row.Cells[4].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                e.Row.Cells[5].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;      
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced the issue. It appears the gridview adds cells in order to have the same number as columns. The only fix I could find was adding the following code in the Page_Load event (you can also add it to any button method - but that's not practical):

```
foreach (GridViewRow gridRow in GridView1.Rows) {
if (gridRow.Cells[0].Text.Contains("Monday") && gridRow.Cells[0].ColumnSpan == 2 && gridRow.Cells.Count == 6)
gridRow.Cells.RemoveAt(5);
}
```

Another solution (with jquery) I found googling but have not tested is here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1413833.aspx/1
Hope it helps!

Comment: No, I'm not sending empty data cell. All cells have data.

This additional cell appears only at the end of Rows which satisfies the IF condition. And that is happening only when I click on some other button in the page, not the button which binds my GridView.